# SQL Insert a datetime from a date + timespan

Tags: sql-server

I'm migrating an old database into a new one and there is a problem cause i'm not sure how can i combine the date and timespan into a datetime.

date is `in dd/MM/yyyy` format
and time is in `hh:mm:ss` format

into my column that is a datetime i just need to add these 2 into dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss

UPDATE

The datatypes are all varchars

date is (varchar(50)
time is varchar(8)

this is in ssms 2017

Comment: Into what version of SQL Server do you migrate?

Comment: Can you confirm the existing columns datatypes?

Comment: updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just cast both to datetime and add

```
DECLARE @date varchar(50) = '06/26/2019'
DECLARE @timespan varchar(8) = '10:29:30'

SELECT CAST(@date AS DATETIME) + CAST(@timespan AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: just tested it out, it actually worked but has to be in this given format. Thanks!